# Conversion specifier of long double in C

Tags: c, mingw

The **long double** data type can have these conversion specifiers in C: %Le,%LE,%Lf,%Lg,%LG ([reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/standlib/ref/printconversionspecifiers.htm)).

I wrote a small program to test :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  long double d = 656546.67894L;
  printf("%.0Le\n",d);
  printf("%.0LE\n",d);
  printf("%.0Lf\n",d);
  printf("%.0Lg\n",d);
  printf("%.0LG\n",d);
  return 0; 
}
```

Output:

-0

-4E-153

-0

-4e-153

-4E-153

But none is giving the desired output, which is 656547 (as you may easily understand).  What is the reason?

The compiler used is gcc version 3.4.2 (mingw-special).

Comment: They all seem to do what I expect.  What is the desired output?

Comment: You won't believe this, but failing to `#include <stdio.h>` is undefined behavior and the programs is free to do anything. Though, for most practical purposes, I'd wager the compiler slipping in the include for you and you really have something else in your _real_ code.

Comment: What does "%.0lf" do for double ?!

For the given d I want the output to be: 656547

Comment: @dirkgently : You are not getting me,I am aware of the problems that may cause due to implicit declaration,I post only a part.

Comment: @Gonzalo: I don't know why but I am not getting the output.

Comment: What compiler/platform are you on?

Comment: I am compiling it in gcc version 3.4.2 (mingw-special),I am aware of the fact that it is old,but don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @nthrgeek - I think that is exactly the problem - MnGW 3.4.5 is printing garbage for me on this.  My other compilers (MSVC, Digital Mars & Comeau) print what you expect.

Comment: Yes I just now checked with in MSVC,it's working fine there.But why in GCC ? I don't think it is implementation defined.A GCC bug ?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the desired results? We know how you initialized 'd', we need to know what it printed.

Comment: Funny - the question includes <cstdio>, so that requires a C++ compiler, not a C compiler?  And the tag is for the wrong language?  FWIW: G++ 4.0.1 on MacOS X gives the outputs 7e+05
7E+05
656547
7e+05
7E+05

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From an [old mingw wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20090919052257/http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/long%20double):

> mingw uses the Microsoft C run-time
> libraries and their implementation of
> printf does not support the 'long
> double' type. As a work-around, you
> could cast to 'double' and pass that
> to printf instead. For example:

```
printf("value = %g\n", (double) my_long_double_value);
```

> Note that a
> similar problem exists for 'long long'
> type. Use the 'I64' (eye sixty-four)
> length modifier instead of gcc's 'll'
> (ell ell). For example:

```
printf("value = %I64d\n", my_long_long_value);
```

Edit (6 years later): Also see the comment below from Keith Thompson for a workaround:

> `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` in the source file or change the command line to `gcc -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1`

Comment: I know this,am not concerned with rounding off,but I want to know why the problem is for long double ?

Comment: Ok. Updating my answer to give you what you want :-)

Comment: Thanks,then it's mingw's fault !

Comment: There's a workaround: `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` in the source file or change the command line to `gcc -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1`.

Comment: The link to the old MinGW wiki is broken, and the relevant page doesn't appear to exist any more, so would someone please edit in an archive link when the edit queues are clear? https://web.archive.org/web/20090919052257/http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/long%20double is the only valid archive URL I could find.

Answer (score 1):

The MinGW C library is provided by MSVCRT.DLL, which is shipped with Windows and is in fact the old VC++ 6.0 library.

MinGW does however use the GNU C++ library, and although that relies on the underlying C library, it does support long double for output using iostreams.  Even if you do not wish to use C++ generally, it may be worth using just enough to support this capability.

Comment: No,the mingw special edition I am using does not support long double.I mean it's giving the same wrong result as before.

Answer (score 0):

**using MinGW-W64 with architecture i686(x86-64 can't work) maybe a solution. I try it and it works.**

**These are compile info:**

```
||=== Build: Debug in TeaErr (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\Practice\TeaErr\main.c||In function 'main':|
D:\Practice\TeaErr\main.c|7|warning: unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [-Wformat=]|
D:\Practice\TeaErr\main.c|7|warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]|
D:\Practice\TeaErr\main.c|7|warning: unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [-Wformat=]|
D:\Practice\TeaErr\main.c|7|warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]|
D:\Practice\TeaErr\main.c|8|warning: unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [-Wformat=]|
D:\Practice\TeaErr\main.c|8|warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]|
D:\Practice\TeaErr\main.c|8|warning: unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [-Wformat=]|
D:\Practice\TeaErr\main.c|8|warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 8 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

**These are my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long double a;
    scanf("%Lf",&a);
    printf("%Lf\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKRJH.png)
[Some Parameters on Install MinGW-W64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tfg6.png)