# scanf GCC for long double

Tags: c, gcc

I'm using gcc 4.8.1 with std=c99 on Windows 7. What's the correct place holder for long double when using `scanf` and `fscanf`? I tried %lf and %Lf and neither is working. Compile command is `gcc -std=c99 main.c -o main.exe`. When I omit `std=c99` it works fine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long double x = 0;
    scanf("%Lf", &x); 
    printf("x = %Lf\n", x); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: **Edit your question** to show the exact source code and the compilation command. Remember to test the return -number of scanned items- from [scanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html) why may fail

Comment: Did you compile with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -g` ? How did you run your program? Why don't you test the result of `scanf`  (e.g. `if (scanf("%Lf", &x)<=0)` ....)

Comment: compilation command: `gcc -std=c99 main.c -o main.exe`. When I don't use `std=c99` it works fine.

Comment: But you should test the result of `scanf`

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working? What output are you getting?

Comment: If you're using MinGW you are probably running into an incompatibility between how GCC and msvcrt.dll represent `long double`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822928/scanf-not-taking-in-long-double and http://stackoverflow.com/a/7136886/12711  Some newer distributions of MinGW may have fixed formatted I/O incompatibilities with `long double` and `long long` (for example, by using custom version of the I/O functions implemented in `libmingwex.a`). An upgrade might be in order (maybe also consider mingw_w64). Or just use `double`.

Comment: I'm getting whatever value I assign to `x` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me, on Centos 6.6, with or without -std=c99:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ gcc x.c -o x -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic
$ ./x
123.456
x = 123.456000

$ gcc x.c -o x  -Wall -pedantic
$ ./x
123.456
x = 123.456000
```

I'm assuming you're on Linux (or Mac OSX), and I assume you're using the libc that matches the installed gcc.

**HOWEVER**

There are issues if you're using GCC with MinGW on Windows:

> [scanf not taking in long double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822928/scanf-not-taking-in-long-double)
>
> Dev-c++ uses MinGW, which uses the gcc compiler and the Microsoft
>   runtime library. Unfortunately, those components disagree on the
>   underlying type to be used for long double (64 vs. 80 or 96 bits, I
>   think). Windows assumes long double is the same size as double; gcc
>   makes long double bigger.
>
> Either choice is valid, but the combination results in a broken C and
>   C++ implementation.

Comment: I'm on windows. I'll edit the question.

Comment: OK, then.  Here are [possible solutions](http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/How-to-printf-long-doubles-td1650580.html): "mingwrt-3.15 onwards[*] provides a fully ANSI conformant printf().
However, it isn't used by default, unless you compile with `-ansi`,
`-posix` or, as JonY suggests, `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`.

Comment: just tired all of those. None works :(

Comment: Please: 1) Verify you have mingwrt or higher (remember: mingw sits on top of GCC; they're distinct); 2) Consider trying `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1`, 3) Consider adding `#define printf __mingw_printf`