# Code::Blocks is giving wrong result when working with long double

Tags: c, ide, double, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks 12.11 on Windows 64-bit platform for C/C++ codes. I recently came across an unexpected result for this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long double number;
    number = 1.1234567;
    printf("%llf\n",number);
    return 0;
}
```

It should print the output 1.1234567 but it gives -0.000000, I figured out that it always gives wrong values when i use long double. This code works fine on ideone http://ideone.com/Opu8cy , Please tell me if there is a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%Lf` for format, not `%llf`.

There could also be a bug in which

```
number = 1.1234567L;
```

could help.

[PRINTF(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

```
   ll     (ell-ell).  A following integer conversion corresponds to a
          long long int or unsigned long long int argument, or a
          following n conversion corresponds to a pointer to a long long
          int argument.

   L      A following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion corresponds
          to a long double argument.  (C99 allows %LF, but SUSv2 does
          not.)
```

---

Also, in Code::Blocks you should go to *Settings -> Compiler and debugger …* and tune up level of warnings. (Preferably to a high level.)

You are perhaps not using GCC (*mingw* or the like) – but if, use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` + some `-std=xxx` or look at answer like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154630/recommended-gcc-warning-options-for-c) – but for your compiler.

Comment: I am using **GCC 4.7 mingw compiler**. After using %Lf and number = 1.1234567L i get the same -0.000000 result. I also added **-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors**, Now it shows me few warning messages  `1. unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [-Wformat] and 2. too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args] ` After adding std=c99 i got correct result without any warning, can anybody tell which c standard code::blocks follows by default. Thanks a lot for suggestions **Sukminder**.

Comment: @AtulKumarVerma: Seems like mingw has [trouble with long double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764350/conversion-specifier-of-long-double-in-c)