# Multiplying long double gives weird output

Tags: c, mingw

```
long double i, j, ans;
scanf("%Lf %Lf", &i, &j);
ans=i*j;
printf("%Lf %Lf", ans, i*j);

i/p -> 1 1
o/p -> -2.000000 -2.000000
expected o/p -> 1.000000 1.000000
```

Please explain this behaviour, and where is it going wrong and how can we come over it?
If the o/p appx to close to 1 also acceptable.

FYI: long double format specifier I tried Lf, lf, LF and llf according to other StackOverflow post.

Comment: %Lf is fine here. It'll surely solve your case.

Comment: I see no problems, could you provide the compilation options you are using?

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double

Comment: Try initialsing your `ans` varible with 0.

Comment: @Jayesh-It won't because both questions have no relationship except for the point which I have already mentioned above, %Lf is fine here.

Comment: @shekharsuman: Initializing `ans` to `0` will make no difference.

Comment: @KeithThompson- Sometimes initialisation matters,just like in Java it gives compilation error if the resulting variable is not initialised.

Comment: [works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4b043343b7e292e), try print return value of `scanf`

Comment: @shekharsuman: No, in this case initializing `ans` to `0` *will make no difference*. A value is assigned to it on the third line of the posted code snippet, overwriting whatever value was used to initialize it.

Comment: @shekharsuman: ans gets assigned to before it gets used.  It is fine.  The initialization to 0 would be redundant.

Comment: Are you using MinGW? As I recall, it has problems with `long double` because the representation used by the compiler (gcc) doesn't match the representation used by Microsoft's runtime library.

Comment: Oh yeah, I told `sometimes` in my point-It is true as said by you guys.

Comment: `%Lf` is the correct format, both for `printf` and for `scanf`.  I don't know where the close votes are coming from; the question is clearly about programming, and it's stated reasonably clearly, with input, output, and expected output. My only suggested improvements are (a) update the question to show a complete self-contained program ([read this](http://sscce.org/) and (b) tell us what platform you're using. This *might* be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1764350/827263).

Comment: I'm running it on CodeBlocks with MinGW32. GCC version 4.7.1.

Comment: @keithThompson Yes. Using MinGW. Have any suggestions ?

Comment: @BryanChen It returns 2. Its working fine.
@ shekhar initialising with ans with 0 didn't make any difference.

Comment: This is a bug in MinGW, caused by its incorrect integration of gcc and Microsoft's runtime library (neither of which is at fault; it's the combination that doesn't work). Computations with `long double` should work correctly, but `printf` and `scanf` do not. Do you really need the full precision of `long double` or would `double` suffice?

Comment: Oh! And Double would be enough and dealing with number values upto 10^18.

Comment: It's not quite that simple. Both `double` and `long double` can represent numbers much bigger than 10^18. For their representable ranges, `long double` usually has better precision. `double` is typically good enough for most purposes; I can't guessing whether it's good enough for yours.

Comment: Bet the result of `scanf("%Lf %Lf", &i, &j);` was not 2.

Comment: @chux: That's an excellent point; the code needs to check the value returned by `scanf`. But I'd bet that the result *is* `2`. If the problem is what I think it is, `scanf` will successfully convert 2 `long double` values -- but it will store them to `i` and `j` with the format used by Microsoft's runtime library, which differs from the format used by the compiler gcc.

Comment: @0g1337h What is the return value of `scanf("%Lf %Lf", &i, &j)`?

Comment: @Keith Thompson  OP confirms your thought.