# Gaussian integral and double division

Tags: c, integral

For fun, I was trying to evaluate the Gaussian integral from 0 to 1 using a series expansion. For this reason, I wrote a factorial function which works well up to 20!(I checked) and then I wrote this:

```
int main(){
    int n;
    long double result=0;
    for(n=0; n<=5; n++){
        if(n%2==0){
            result+=(((long double) 1/(long double)(factorial(n)*(2*n+1))));
        } else {
            result-=(((long double) 1/(long double)(factorial(n)*(2*n+1))));
        }
    }        
    printf("The Gaussian integral from 0 to 1 is %Lf\n", result);
}
```

This gives me a strange negative number which is obviously not even close. I suspect the problem is with the cast, but I don't know what it is. Any thoughts? This is not the first thing I tried. I tried converting anything in the expression and putting the explicit cast at the beginning, but it didn't work.

Comment: what is the result of `factorial(0)`?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/VLgnoS

Comment: It's 1, I addressed the problem when I was writing the function.

Comment: What compiler are you using? If it's MinGW, it doesn't handle `long double` properly.

Comment: I'm using Dev-C++ with the default GCC compiler.

Comment: On Windows?    [...]

Comment: Dev-C++ tells me it's the default GCC compiler, I frankly don't remember. EDIT: Yep, it's MinGW.

Comment: For future reference: best to include in your post the unexpected output as in the "strange negative number" and your expected output.  These 2 things help solve problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the MinGW compiler (port of gcc for Windows), which has issues with the `long double` type. This is due to conflicts between GCC's implementation of `long double` and Microsoft's C library. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764350/conversion-specifier-of-long-double-in-c).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double), defining `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` may solve this. If not, using `double` instead will work.

Comment: An impressive feat of deduction.

Answer (score 2):

In `(long double)(factorial(n)*(2*n+1)`, the multiplications are integer multiplications and the first one could overflow if the result of `factorial` is already close to the limit of the integer type used.

Write `((long double)(factorial(n))*(2*n+1)` so that the first multiplication is a floating-point multiplication.

Comment: `n<=5` here, so it shouldn't overflow.

Comment: @interjay Yes. I have to assume that the code shown in the question is not exactly the one that overflows. However, assuming a factorial function that works for the values passed to it and returns some integer type (not specified in the question), the integer multiplication by `2*n+1` is the obvious red flag in the question, and converting immediately to floating-point is the simplest remedy.

Comment: OP claims "factorial function which works well up to 20!". I doubt that as it would overflow even a 64 bit integer. So I agree with Pascal - this is not an SSCCE. So +1 answer (even if mine is cuter).

Comment: @Bathsheba 20! ~ 2.432902e+18 is close to the limit of 64-bit signed integers. But if `factorial` returns a 64-bit signed integer, why would `factorial(5)` cause any trouble? Hmmm...

Comment: Regarding the 20! thing: it's a naive algoritm, designed for not many digits of precision. However, I checked on Wolfram and 20! is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost certainly overflowing your integer type. In C this is technically *undefined behaviour*.

For 32 bit unsigned integer, 13! will overflow. On 64 bit, 21! will overflow.

Your algorithm will survive a little longer if you use a floating point `double` type or an extension like `__uint128` (gives you, I think, up to 34!) if your compiler supports it.

Another problem that you have is that you are progressively adding terms of decreasing size to your total. That's never a good idea when working with floating point types. If you run your `for` loop in the reverse order then the result will be more accurate.

Comment: It works with double, albeit with 6 digits of precision. How could I do a bit more?

Comment: a suggestion for improvement added to the answer