# Using long double in C gives weird results after subtraction

Tags: c, double

I just started learning C and I have a very funny problem. I will let the code speak for itself. On scanf I give the value **25.15**:

```
long double input;
scanf("%Lf", &input);
printf("%Lf\n", input); //its correctly 25.150000
input = input - 0.75;
printf("%Lf\n", input); //Instead of something resembling 24.4 I get -2
```

How is it possible that 25.15 - 0.75 gives me -2?

Comment: It works fine here https://www.ideone.com/z7uC3i what is your platform, compiler, version OS, etc.?

Comment: Unable to replicate this.

Comment: Works fine on my Linux box.  Tested on gcc 4.8.3 and clang 6.0.0 svn.

Comment: It works perfect for me on VS13 and on GCC too.

Comment: windows 10 build 15063, TDM-GCC 5.1.0-3 (displays 1.1309.0 on control panel )

Comment: Cannot reproduce in MSVC which outputs `24.400000`

Comment: Problem solved as it was caused by the implementation of long double on the mingw compiler for windows. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have same problem as you in CodeBlocks. Works perfectly with double.. Done some [googling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764350/conversion-specifier-of-long-double-in-c). It seems its known problem. Also try googling "long double giving wrong results c", i hope you will find your answer there.

Comment: Also using codeblocks. How is it possible that an IDE is causing this and not a well known compiler?

Comment: I honestly don't know, looks very strange. If you find any more detailed answer about this behaviour, please leave comment here. :))

Comment: @itsUndefined, read the answers to the question Mare linked.  They claim that the problem is in the Microsoft C library on which Mingw32 binaries rely.  Thus, it is not your IDE, but rather your operating environment.  Microsoft has never been overly interested in providing a conforming C (or C library) implementation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I figured that out after I read the link. I just thought it's the IDE because it was stated by Mare70.

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks and I tell you that you wrong.

Comment: @itsUndefined `I just thought it's the IDE because it was stated by Mare70` You do not need an IDE to test that Code.

Comment: Yeah man I completely understand now the relation between the two. I could as easily write the code using notepad and then call the compiler from the command line prompt.