# about %Lf and %Le can not print rightly

Tags: c, windows, mingw

I ran a program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
float aboat = 32000.0;
double abet = 2.14e9;
long double dip =5.32e-5;

printf("%f can be written %e\n",aboat,aboat);
printf("And it's %a in hexadecimal, powers of 2 notation\n",aboat);
printf("%f can be written %e\n",abet, abet);
printf("%Lf can be written %Le\n",dip,dip);
                      \\ this statement can not print rightly 
return 0;
}
```

but it print like this :

```
32000.000000 can be written 3.200000e+004
And it's 0x1.f40000p+14 in hexadecimal, powers of 2 notation
2140000000.000000 can be written 2.140000e+009
-1950228512509697500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0
00000 can be written 272.500183
```

as you can see , this result must be  incorrect. but I can not find error, so is it a bug attribute to IDE ? I use JetBrains CLion 2017.3.4.

thanks for remind.this is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(untitled1 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(untitled1 main.c)
```

And the gcc version is 6.3.0

Comment: No, the IDE is irrelevant since it is not the IDE which compiles and executes the program. The problem, if there is any, is with the *compiler*. So please tell us which compiler you are using, and which flags you have specified for it (in short, please edit your question to include the `CMakeLists.txt` file as well, and the output of e.g. `gcc --version` if you use GCC).

Comment: Is this on Windows with MinGW gcc? I have this vague memory that there was some problem using `long double` on MinGW because it uses Microsoft libraries.

Comment: Yes, but how can I solve this problem? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion specifier of long double in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764350/conversion-specifier-of-long-double-in-c)

Comment: The last line looks fine to me, and it prints `0.000053 can be written 5.320000e-05` under my compiler and C library.  I conclude there's something wrong with yours.

Comment: That's a problem with mingw.