# C programming help needed : pointers and malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

The output should be *"the wallet belongs to Warren Buffett with balance of 85500000000"* but I am getting *"The wallet belongs to Warren Buffett with balance of 0.000000"*. Can you please let me know where am I making the mistake?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *owner;
    long double balance;
} Wallet;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const char *owner = "Warren Buffett";
    Wallet *wallet = (Wallet *) malloc(sizeof(Wallet));
    wallet->owner = (char *) malloc(strlen(owner) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(wallet->owner, "Warren Buffett");
    wallet->balance = 85500000000;
    printf("The wallet belongs to %s with balance of %Lf",
           wallet->owner, wallet->balance);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't malloc enough space - strings have a null terminator

Comment: also if you are using GCC in Windows, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764350/conversion-specifier-of-long-double-in-c)

Comment: @Axifive: Try with AddressSanitizer and you'll see [not so much](https://godbolt.org/z/rMbqeM5dG).  Can onlinegdb enable ASan?

Comment: An off-topic warning about using floating point numbers for currency: you shouldn't. Floating point numbers are approximations with unexpected edge cases (e.g `(0.1 + 0.2) == 0.3` is `false`). Better to use the smallest quantity (e.g. cents or 1/00 of a cent or whatever is appropriate) and use well established banking rounding rules when multiplying or dividing.

Comment: Remember, for future sake, to always `free()` what you `malloc()`. In the code above (no recursion, no loops, no functions except `main()`, ...) there's no big harm by leaving the memory marked as "in use" when the program terminates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not allocating enough space for `wallet->owner`.

Strings in C consist of a sequence of characters followed by a terminating null byte.  You're allocating `strlen(owner) * sizeof(char)` bytes for `wallet->owner` which is enough for the characters in the string but not for the terminating null byte.  As a result, you're writing past the end of allocated memory.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which can manifest as unexepected output.

Add 1 to the allocated space:

```
wallet->owner = malloc(strlen(owner) + 1);
```

Also, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 so the multiplication by that can be omitted, and [you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).